# How to securely provide AWS Credentials to Docker Container locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

A few developers and I are working on a project that involves utilizing the boto3 library for Python and needed to make calls to AWS Cognito for our project. Currently, we use AWS IAM Identity Center and Google Workspace as our external Identity Provider to allow developers to be granted short-term AWS credentials. Our current development setup involves using docker (locally not in AWS) to containerize our backend and frontend to make it easier for developers to setup their environments.

I wasn't sure what would be the best way in our case to pass credentials over to the containers. Should developers have aws-cli installed locally and then pass over credentials as environment variables to our containers or would it be better to install aws-cli within Docker and run the necessary commands for SSO login? Or would it make more sense to create an IAM role and have it be assumed during local development to avoid needing to refresh credentials?

Any input on this would be appreciated as I am still very new to AWS and would like to setup my project with best practices in mind.

Ideas I had in mind

- AWS CLI installation in Docker
- Local installation of AWS CLI and passing credentials as env variables
- Setting up a IAM role to be assumed during local development.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Generally, the [answer is](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-guide-to-locally-testing-containers-with-amazon-ecs-local-endpoints-and-docker-compose/) to mount the .aws folder locally so it can load credentials, then allow it to reach out to the metadata server when running in production.